# "ValueError: too many values to unpack" while deploying Django app to AWS

Tags: python, django, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my Django app to AWS using this documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_django.html

Everything goes fine uptil the last step: git aws.push

It returns the following error:

```
DCs-MacBook-Pro:ssite deeptichopra$ git aws.push
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push", line 41, in <module>
    dev_tools = DevTools()
  File "/Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/ssite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/dev_tools.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.beanstalk_config = ElasticBeanstalkConfig(os.getcwd())
  File "/Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/ssite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/elastic_beanstalk_config.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.set_credential_settings()
  File "/Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/ssite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/elastic_beanstalk_config.py", line 108, in set_credential_settings
    self.credential_settings = self.credential_file["global"]
  File "/Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/ssite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/ini.py", line 59, in __getitem__
    return section.to_h()
  File "/Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/ssite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/ini.py", line 39, in to_h
    (key, value) = line.split("=")
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

The mysite.config file in mysite/.ebextensions:

```
container_commands:
  01_syncdb:    
    command: “manage.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python
    option_name: WSGIPath
    value: ssite/wsgi.py
  - option_name: DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
    value: ssite.settings
```

The config file in .elasticbeanstalk folder:

```
[global]
ApplicationName=ssite
AwsCredentialFile=/Users/deeptichopra/.elasticbeanstalk/aws_credential_file
DevToolsEndpoint=git.elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
EnvironmentName=ssite-env
EnvironmentTier=WebServer::Standard::1.0
EnvironmentType=SingleInstance
InstanceProfileName=aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
OptionSettingFile=/Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/ssite/.elasticbeanstalk/optionsettings.ssite-env
RdsDeletionPolicy=Snapshot
RdsEnabled=Yes
RdsSourceSnapshotName=
Region=ap-southeast-1
ServiceEndpoint=https://elasticbeanstalk.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
SolutionStack=64bit Amazon Linux 2014.09 v1.0.9 running Python 2.7
```

The app runs fine on the local server. What could be wrong?

Comment: The traceback is telling you that line has more than one `=` in it. Try printing line to see what its contents are.

Comment: But the lines it is pointing to are from the aws code. I have not edited anything there, just downloaded it.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `~/.elasticbeanstalk/aws_credential_file` file. Do not post the contents here.

Do any of the values/passwords have the `=` in them? That's your problem.

The python script provided by Amazon splits the line on `=`, but they don't tell you anywhere that you can't use `=` in your password.

Comment: Thank you! I couldn't possibly have guessed that!

Answer (score -2):

Seems that something is wrong with your Elastic Beanstalk config file. Can you post the content of the file **.elasticbeanstalk/config** ?

The .elasticbeanstalk hidden directory should be present in the root of your git working copy.

Comment: I think this should better be posted as a comment. Because this isn't an answer

Comment: I think that the issue is with the config file, that's an anwser IMHO, although is partial. To enhance my answer I asked the opener to post the file, so that I could expand and complete my answer.

Comment: You mean the mysite.config file in mysite/.ebextensions? I added that in the question.

Comment: You should have a directory called .elasticbeanstalk in your mysite folder, don't you?

Comment: The file looks ok, you can try to debug the code adding the line

`print line`

at line 39 of /Users/deeptichopra/Desktop/ssite/.git/AWSDevTools/aws/ini.py file.
You should see the lines of your config printed, and the problematic line printed just before the error.